# PHP Function not functioning correctly with array when variables are in a different order

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a PHP function. The function checks names and, if they do not exist, dies.  It strips out spaces from the names, and adds the name of the current user logged in if they are not already in the list.

```
function create_group($name, $description, $invites){
    global $link;
    $invitesarr = explode(',', $invites);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; //avoids issues with quotations (either invalid quotation for referring to PHP variable or repeated double quotes)
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
    foreach($result as $resul){
        foreach($resul as $resu){
            $logged_in_username = $resu;
        }}
    if(in_array($logged_in_username, $invitesarr)){
    }else{
        $invitesarr[] = $logged_in_username;
    }

    foreach($invitesarr as $invite) {
        $idres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$invite'");
        $invite = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $invite);
        print $invite;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($idres) == 0) {
            exit("1 or more of the users that you entered do(es) not exist!");
        }
    }

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $description);
    $names = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `group_name` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_name` = '$name'");
    $descriptions = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `group_description` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_description` = '$description'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($names) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($descriptions) == 0) {
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `groups` (`group_name`, `group_description`) VALUES ('$name', '$description')");
    } else {
        echo 'Group with that name/description already exists.';
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `group_id` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_name` = '$name'");

    foreach($result as $resul) {
        foreach($resul as $resu) {
            $group_id = $resu;
        }
    }
    foreach($invitesarr as $invite) {
        $idres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$invite'");
        foreach($idres as $idarr) {
            foreach($idarr as $id) {
                mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `group_members` (`group_id`, `user_id`, `confirmed?`) VALUES ('$group_id', '$id', 0)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, except for when a user enters their name and it goes into the $invitesarr array. When I put a print statement in the foreach statement that checks names, I notice that, when the user's name is not entered into the field (which posts) the names are in the order name1 loggedinname, whereas when I enter the user's name it becomes loggedinname name1.  This seems to be significant.

Comment: `mysqli_query` doesn't return an array. You have to call `mysqli_fetch_XXX` in a loop to get the results of the query.

Comment: Never mind, I see that Iterator support was added to `mysqli_result` in PHP 5.4.0, so you can use it with `foreach`.

Comment: Why do you use `foreach` loops for queries that just return one row and one column? It makes the code very confusing.

Comment: What doesn't work? I don't see any way that this code could be dependent on the order of the elements of `$invitesarr`.

Comment: Try trimming the elements of `$invitesarr`, in case the user puts a space before or after the comma.

Comment: There are lots of ways that this code could be improved, like using `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the ID of the group that was created, combining the `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries at the end, and not using unnecessary `foreach` loops. But I don't think any of them have anything to do with whatever problem you're having.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know why the order should change how it works and I guess it might be something else but I can't think what.  I have trimmed the elements down (with the preg_replace)

Comment: You're not doing that in the loop that does `if(in_array())`

Comment: You still haven't explained what's wrong with the script. All you said is that it works perfectly some times, you didn't say what goes wrong in the other cases.

Comment: @Barnmar sorry, I tried doing that in if(in_array()) but it didn't appear to make a difference, assumedly because it then gets the spaces deleted from it in the following foreach.  I get the exit("1 or more users you entered do(es) not exist") when I shouldn't; that is the thing that goes wrong, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put:

```
$invite = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $invite);
```

*before* the line:

```
$idres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$invite'");
```

Comment: That works!  What an idiot I was!  I would vote you up if I had enough rep

Comment: Accepting the answer is better than upvoting.